Does the zero-point energy get less dense as space expands?
As the title says, we know that the universe is expanding, with it I am assuming that all the related quantum fields are also expanding so that we have the "same" conditions everywhere in space.
Q1: If that is the case is the zero-point energy getting less dense like a balloon (the bigger it gets the less dense / more stretched everything becomes)?
Q2: If however the zero-point energy has the same density as space expands (creating energy), doesn't that break the laws of thermodynamics?

Doesnt the expansion of the universe break classical thermodynamics?So since there is something which breaks apart classical thermodynamics I dont see why there shouldnt be another thing.

"the zero-point energy" What zero-point energy?
